# Python console_scripts doesn't work when pip install --user

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I wrapped my code into python package and now I want it to be also runnable from the command line (linux). So I added console_scripts tag to setup.py and all seems to be working fine when I pip install it as a root.
(I can run program from the command line)

However I'd also like for a package to be installed by using

pip install --user .

so it can be installed on computers when root is not available to the user. However when I try to invoke program from the command line i got 'command not found'. The pip installation finishes successfully and I can still run it using

python my_prog.py

But I wonder is there any solution to this problem.
Can someone please explain how the console_scripts setup.py tag actually works?

Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

pip installs the scripts under `~/.local/bin`. You need to add this to your `PATH` with:

```
export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: is there any way to add this path to PATH using python/pip or even better check is it there and if not found add it?

Comment: Not with pip, no. Although, from the sounds of this [issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3813), it may print a warning soon if it isn't in your `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where is this documented?