# How to create a python library which can be used as shell command after installation?

Tags: python

Some python packages such as `flask` can be used as shell script after installation via `pip install`. My question is how to create them?

A minimal package can be written as below, and where to add codes?

```
.
├── library_name
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── Foo.py
└── setup.py
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think you'll find https://chriswarrick.com/blog/2014/09/15/python-apps-the-right-way-entry_points-and-scripts/ useful

Answer (score 2):

Use the entrypoints in your setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='Foo',
    version='1.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    url='https://github.com/Bar/Foo.git',
    install_requires=[

    ],
    license='',
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',

    ],
    keywords='foo bar',
    author='Mr Foo',

    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'foo = library_name.Foo:main',
        ],
    },
)
```

This way when you python setup.py install you can call foo from shell and it will execute main in Foo.py

Note that you need to change library_name, foo, Foo and main in case they have different names in your code.

Comment: May be we also need to add PATH: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46973667/python-console-scripts-doesnt-work-when-pip-install-user

Comment: no that is bad practice, use the virtualenv to modify PATH, don't mess with it manually

Comment: What I mean is don't install ANYTHING, EVER if you are not in a virtualenvironment. That will also solve your path problem in this case.